# Can a 501(c)(7) social club receive donations from a political organization?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-profit

We are a 501(c)(7) social club. We are doing a fundraising event and a political organization would like to donate to our program. Is this permitted?

Comment: You would probably want to consult a lawyer. If the *program* to which the donation is made is part of the club's social function then it *may be* OK. If the program is of political nature then you would likely have an issue. But IANAL, this is a question to your attorney.

Comment: what is the fundraising money going towards?